# RegEx Split - keeping the punctuations

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a sentence that looks like this:

```
"what is this? i want this to work. blah"
```

How do I get an array with the punctuations included looking like this?

```
[0] = what is this?
[1] = i want this to work.
[2] = blah
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your sample text, split on `(?<=[.?!])\s*`.

Other than that I want to add that splitting a text into sentences reliably with regex is impossible.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Will accept the answer as soon as SO allows me to.

Comment: if it ends properly with "blah." instead there are 4 sentences after split, last is null

Comment: @Alan Moore you suggest that hello.bye. is once sentence?

Comment: @Valentin: Yes, then it would be four parts. You could add a look-ahead to catch this case: `(?<=[.?!])\s*(?=\S+)` but as I said, *real* natural language sentence recognition is impossible with regex anyway.

Comment: @Valentin How about `Is your email valentin.kuzub@myemail.com?` Is that three sentences?

Comment: like Tomalak says.. its hard to solve a task of splitting sentence using regex. Some entities do call for special treatment, like emails. If sample text doesn't contain much emails I think * suits better

Comment: @Valentin I did not say "hard". I said "impossible". Important difference right there. ;)

Comment: once you say "impossible" it becomes much more difficult to prove that statement. "hard" appears axiomatic ;)

Comment: @Valentin Actually it is not difficult to prove this statement. Regular expressions describe [regular languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language). Regular languages are *very* limited. Natural language is *anything but* regular. Hence it cannot be parsed with regex. Just like HTML (and HTML already has simpler and more strictly defined rules than natural language). It's the "not even when hell freezes over" kind of impossible.

Comment: well lets limit outrselves to english language, and work out a definition of sentence. After all I think a person can easily identify a sentence and its end. Given that I think there is a set of rules defining englih statements. Now I am not sure its impossible to fill this set into regexes, of various types, split by | until we run out of ideas. I am now not sure that won't be possible if task was given.

Comment: @Valentin *Severely* limiting the problem domain until we no longer have a natural language is the only way. And as soon as you involve "host language" control structures you are writing a parser and we are not talking about regular expressions anymore. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Regex.Split` to match on whitespace preceded by punctuation.

```
Regex.Split(input, "(?<=[.?!])\s+");
```

`(?<=)` is a lookbehind group. It checks that the match is preceded by the group, but doesn't capture it.

Comment: `preg_* is not available in C# ;)

Comment: Dang, you got your answer in while I was typing mine. :p Had same solution.

Comment: yeah, i changed it to `ReExp.Split()`. Didn't read the language tag.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a method which does sub-string substitution. With Ruby's `gsub`, for example:

```
"I am a lion. Hear me roar! Where is my cub? Never mind, found him.".gsub(/[.?!]/, '\0|').split('|')
=> ["I am a lion.", " Hear me roar!", " Where is my cub?", " Never mind, found him."]
```

This assumes the definition of a sentence is something that ends with `.`, `?` or `!` of course. An ellipsis (`...`) would screw it up a bit.